# how can i makemigrations django models in custom path?

Tags: python, django

I want create practice web game using python(django) + javascript

my project name is `lucifer`

the path is

```
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── lucifer
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── game
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── character
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── models
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       └── character.py
│   │   └── skill
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── models
│   │           ├── __init__.py
│   │           └── skill.py
│   ├── lucifer
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── views
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── posts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── models
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   └── views
│   └── users
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── admin
│       ├── models
│       ├── templates
│       └── views
```

the app is posts, users, game

and models of game are in game app,

**INSTALLED_APP**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ... #

    'rest_framework',
    'django_summernote',

    'lucifer',
    'users',
    'posts',

    'game',
]
```

when I `manage.py makemigrations users posts game`

character, skill model does not migrations..

how can i makemigrations my game's models?

thank you

**game/__init__.py**

```
from .character import models
from .skills import models
```

**game/character/__init__.py**

```
# none
```

**game/character/models/__init__.py**

```
from models.character import Character
```

**game/skill/__init__.py**

```
# none
```

**game/skill/models/__init__.py**

```
from models.skill import Skill
```

Comment: import all your models in __init__.py

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL Thank you about your advise, but doesn't working too

Comment: Can you show all init.py

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL I add init.py thank you!

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL ummm I solved my problem using Appconfig [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165198/apps-arent-loaded-yet-with-signals) but, thank you very much about your kind advice.

Answer (score -1):

For Character and Skill you have a different folder structure, have you made any changes to accept this structure?

I you don't need you can put your Character and Skill models inside the models.py and delete their model directories:

```
│   ├── game
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── character
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── models.py
│   └── skill
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── models.py
│   ...
```

EDIT:

In any case, the name of the application to be called is character and skill and not the game app.

```
python manage.py makemigrations character
```

You can see the applications that are affected by the migrate

```
python manage.py migrate --list
```

Comment: Try to see your apps: manage.py migrate --list (Your apps should be character and skill, not game)